# Tem como listar todos os namespaces a partir de um específico?

Tags: php, php-autoload, autoload, spl-autoloader-register

Preciso instanciar uma classe passando apenas o nome dela e tentar instanciar ela em vários nemapaces diferentes até conseguir. O Framework não aceita instanciar nenhuma classe sem o namespace, porque ele entende que a classe esta no namespace corrente, eu poderia setar o namespace na hora de instanciar a classe, mas o problema é que nem sempre essa classe terá esse mesmo namespace.

Tenho o namespace:

> App\Programa

Eu queria listar todos os namespaces apartir do namespace citado acima, exemplo:

> App\Programa\Teste
>
> App\Programa\Controle
>
> App\Programa\Dominio\Base

Existe alguma forma de listar isso ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver esse problema usado a psr-4, e mapiei os namespaces da forma que eu queria.